# CoreData (NSPredicate)

Tags: xcode, swift, coredata

Нужно отфильтровать Базу и показать только те ячейки которые были изменены меньше минуты назад.

Когда ячейка обновляется я меняю ей параметр

```
mapPoint["lastUpdate"] = NSDate()
```

Подскажите как мне правильно сделать NSPredicate

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MapPoint")
let startInterval = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60).timeIntervalSince1970

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"lastUpdate > %@", startInterval)
```

Такой способ почему-то не работает...

Comment: не уверен, что можно сравнивать NSDate используя больше/меньше. может попробуйте сконвертировать в timestamp и их уже сравнивать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сравниваете `NSDate` с `NSTimeInterval`(ну т.е. `Double`).

Либо сохраняйте `NSTimeInterval`, либо в `NSPredicate` сравнивайте даты.